# print triangles with validation numbers

Tags: javascript

I have code like this, I want the output like this "must be number" if the input is a string

```
let a = "five";
    for (let i = a; i >= 1; i--) {
      let output = "";
      for (let j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
        output = j + output;
      }
    
      if (typeof a !== "number") {
        console.log("must be numbers!");
      } else {
        console.log(output);
      }
    }
```

is there something wrong with my code? Please help. thank you

Comment: Your first for loop wont execute since you have initialized `i = a`, `"five" >= 1` is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, you had a for loop already including `a` even when it wasn't yet checked to see if it was faulty or not, you're in for a crazy roller coaster ride. it's always important to check for things that can de-rail a process before running the process(in your case, a data-type issue). the code below shows how to implement what i was talking about

```js
let a = "five";
  if (typeof a != "number") { //!= instead of !== as !== is STRICT not equal whereas != is basically not equal(BIG DIFFERENCE)
    console.log("must be numbers!");
  }
  else {
    for (let i = a; i >= 1; i--) {
      let output = "";
      for (let j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
        output = j + output;
      }
      console.log(output);
    }
  }
//I shall assume you're new to coding and i'll say that another way to check that condition is isNaN(varName). if it returns true, varName isn't a number, and if false, varName is a number
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you enter your loop, you will want to check `typeof a`.

```
let a = "five";
if (typeof a !== "number") {
  console.log("must be a number")
} else {
  for (...) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if a is not a number before you run your for loop.

Like this:

```
let a = "five";

    if (typeof a !== "number") {
        console.log("must be numbers!");
      } 
 
 else {
      for (let i = a; i >= 1; i--) {
        let output = "";

        for (let j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
           output = j + output;
        }
       console.log(output);
      }     
    }
```